# Asynctask onPostExecutive method assigning a value to instance variable but it is not showing that in mainActivity class.

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a instance variable(art) of main activity class getting assigned with a value in onPostExecution method.Log statements prints the value of art in onPostExecute method.

But the value of art is null after the onPostExecute method.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
ListView listView1;
String[] dummyData = {"sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday","monday","tuesday",
        "wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
ArrayList<String> summery = new ArrayList<String>(4);
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>(4);
Elements art;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    String stringUrl = "https://techcards.wordpress.com";
    Fetch fetch = new Fetch();
    fetch.execute(stringUrl);


    try{
         for (int i =0;i<art.size() ;i++ ) {

             Log.v("articles after post executive",art.get(i).toString());
             links.add(i,art.get(i).getElementsByTag("a").toString());
             Log.v("links",art.toString());
             summery.add(i,art.get(i).getElementsByTag("p").text());

         }

     }catch(NullPointerException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("art is null");
     }




    listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.single_row,R.id.textView2, links);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String text =(String) t.getText();
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//this makeText is a static method
}

// Fetch AsyncTask
private class Fetch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Elements> {

    @Override
    protected Elements doInBackground(String... params) {
        Elements articles = null;

        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            Element main =doc.getElementById("content").getElementById("primary").
                    getElementById("main");

            articles = main.getElementsByClass("entry-summary");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IO exception");
        }

        return articles;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {

        art = result;
        for (int i =0;i<art.size() ;i++ ) {
            Log.v("links in post executive",art.get(i).getElementsByTag("a").toString());
            Log.v("summery in post executive",art.get(i).getElementsByTag("p").text());
        }
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

art is giving null pointer exception when i'm trying to use it to update links and summery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPostExecute` method run when `doInBackground` execution complete. so add data in adapter in `onPostExecute` instead of just after starting `AsyncTask` :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);

   // 1. Add data in summery from result
   // 2. Pass summery to Adapter constructor 
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.single_row,
                                                R.id.textView2, links);
     listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: very helpful :), I have a general doubt...so when we are programming in java,it is imperative style,,,our code runs in a sequence(for most situations),So should we write all the code that comes after AsyncTask and which is dependent on asyncTask  in the onPostExecutive method.. ??

Comment: and one more doubt ..why  are you calling onPostExecute method of super class?? I haven't done this ,but the code still working fine.

Comment: @nagSumanth: yes move code inside onpostexecute method which u want to run according to Asyctask result and calling onpostexecute do nothing but this line is added by default by IDE when overriding Asyctask method

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask works asynchronously. **Those lines after:**

```
fetch.execute(stringUrl);
```

**doesn't work after** `onPostExecute` but it works simultaneously (or so) with the code inside AsyncTask. That's why AsyncTask is called AsyncTask.

And that's why your art variable is null since onPostExecute doesn't get called yet.